# How to declare a dictionary with a struct value

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have this definition

```
struct SData {
  var OldValue: Float
  var Values: [Float]
  var Times: [UInt32]
}
var Symbols: [String:SData]
```

This gives error at `Symbols` declaration "*Global 'var' declaration requires an initializer expression or getter/setter...*". When I make it like `[String:SData]()` this time it says "*Consecutive statements on line must be separated by ';'*".

How can I declare a dictionary with a struct value type, and the struct has some arrays in it? (Adding `()` to arrays within the struct also gives the second error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
var Symbols = [String:SData]()
```

Test Data

```
var symbols = [String:SData]()
let test = SData(OldValue: 2.2, Values: [1.1], Times: [UInt32(22)])
symbols["Thing"] = test

// use lower case for variable names as well
```

Comment: Or you can initialize it to an empty dictionary `var Symbols:[String:SData] = [:]`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable Symbols is not declared as an optional so it has to be initialized.

The first solution is to initialize it directly:

```
var Symbols: [String:SData] = [String:SData]()
```

or to declare it as an optional so it can be created later.

```
var Symbols: [String:SData]?
```